# How to know when particular View from layout is Displayed which is in RecyclerView

Tags: android, view

I have a complex layout which is being used in Recycler View. So I want to know when some particular view, let's say Title TextView, is displayed.

And this RecyclerView is in ViewPager. So I need a callback only when that child of ViewPager is displayed.

So that way, I want analytics for which RecycleView item is already been displayed.

How do I achieve this? Is there any callback method for the same? or I just need to add layoutChangeListener or addOnGlobalLayoutListener for View and check for that particular View is displayed by checking Rect of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

private static int firstVisibleInListview;
firstVisibleInListview = yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

In your scroll listener:

```
 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int currentFirstVisible = yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (currentFirstVisible > firstVisibleInListview) {
        Log.i("RecyclerView scrolled: ", "scroll up!");
    } else {
        Log.i("RecyclerView scrolled: ", "scroll down!");
    }
    firstVisibleInListview = currentFirstVisible;
}
```

Same as you can get Last visible item.

thanks